# Streamlit login solution need to click on "Login" button twice to login

Tags: python, streamlit

Login button need to be clicked twice. Ideally single click should work.

```
import streamlit as st


# Function to check login credentials
def login(username, password):
    return username == "a" and password == "b"

# Main function
def main():
    st.title("abc")

# Get session state
if "login_successful" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.login_successful = False
if "username" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.username = ""
if "password" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.password = ""

# If login is successful, display "Hello"
if st.session_state.login_successful:
    st.write("Hello")
else:
    # Display login form
    st.session_state.username = st.text_input("Username:", value=st.session_state.username)
    st.session_state.password = st.text_input("Password:", type="password", value=st.session_state.password)

    # Check login credentials
    if st.button("Login"):
        if login(st.session_state.username, st.session_state.password):
            # Update session state on successful login
            st.session_state.login_successful = True
        else:
            st.warning("Wrong username or password.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```